# How to create new columns using groupby based on logical expressions

Tags: pandas, csv, pandas-groupby

I have this CSV file

http://www.sharecsv.com/s/2503dd7fb735a773b8edfc968c6ae906/whatt2.csv

I want to create three columns, 'MT_Value','M_Value', and 'T_Data', one who has the mean of the data grouped by year and month, which I accomplished by doing this.

`data.groupby(['Year','Month']).mean()`

But for M_value I need to do the mean of only the values different from zero, and for T_Data I need the count of the values that are zero divided by the total of values, I guess that for the last one I need to divide the amount of values that are zero by the amount of total data grouped, but honestly I am a bit lost. I looked on google and they say something about transform but I didn't understood very well

Thank you.

Comment: *... for T_Data I need all of the values that are zero divided by the total of values*, isn't it `0`?

Comment: Hi, I am awful at explaining but I meant like the count of data that it is zero divided by the total count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
(data.assign(M_Value=data.Valor.where(data.Valor!=0),
            T_Data=data.Valor.eq(0))
     .groupby(['Year','Month'])
     [['Valor','M_Value','T_Data']]
     .mean()
)
```

Explanation: `assign` will create new columns with respective names. Now

1. `data.Valor.where(data.Valor!=0)` will replace `0` values with `nan`, which will be ignored when we call `mean()`.
2. `data.Valor.eq(0)` will replace `0` with `1` and other values with `0`. So when you do `mean()`, you compute `count(Valor==0)/total_count()`.

Output:

```
                Valor    M_Value    T_Data
Year Month                                
1970 1       2.306452   6.500000  0.645161
     2       1.507143   4.688889  0.678571
     3       2.064516   7.111111  0.709677
     4      11.816667  13.634615  0.133333
     5       7.974194  11.236364  0.290323
...               ...        ...       ...
1997 10      3.745161   7.740000  0.516129
     11     11.626667  21.800000  0.466667
     12      0.564516   4.375000  0.870968
1998 1       2.000000  15.500000  0.870968
     2       1.545455   5.666667  0.727273

[331 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: If I wanted to add as well, let's say the max and minimum value for 'Valor' do I need to use .agg( )? Thank you again, I am really new into programming and Pandas is really giving me a hard time.

Comment: Yes, agg is the way to go.